# MongoDB Differentiates Between undefined vs. null

Tags: mongodb

I was checking logic for querying on non-values and noticed when using the `mongo` shell, it differentiates between `undefined` and `null` values.

```
> use test
> db.test.insert({ a : 1,          b : null,       c : undefined })
> db.test.insert({ a : null,       b : undefined,  c : 1 })
> db.test.insert({ a : undefined,  b : 1,          c : null })
```

When you query on the collection, you get this:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d95575c9333565e80ccb22"), "a" : 1, "b" : null, "c" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d9557fc9333565e80ccb23"), "a" : null, "b" : null, "c" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d95586c9333565e80ccb24"), "a" : null, "b" : 1, "c" : null }
```

When you query on `null` however, it only retrieves records who was explicitly set to `null`.

```
> db.test.find({ a : null })
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d9557fc9333565e80ccb23"), "a" : null, "b" : null, "c" : 1 }
```

Is this a bug in MongoDB?  <strike>How can I properly query for null/ undefined/ non-set fields?</strike>

## EDIT

So I can query for not-set values with this:

```
db.test.find({ $or : [ { a : null }, { a : { $exists : false } } ] })
```

But in this example though, it still only returns the single record:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52d9557fc9333565e80ccb23"), "a" : null, "b" : null, "c" : 1 }
```

Anyone know why/ how MongoDB differentiates between `undefined` and `null`?  Is this an issue with how the data was entered in MongoDB?

Comment: Mongo bug - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6102. Even though the shell shows the undefined value as null, it is a value that still exists but is not null (it's a special undefined value). If you don't want `a` to be defined on the record, just don't include it.

Comment: @JeffStorey Right, this was just something I stumbled upon when testing queries.  If you want to throw this Jira issue into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to return a document where a field exists AND is not null, use `{ a : {$ne : null}}`

Undefined and null values are different, but the shell shows them both as null - https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6102

Comment: I'm more interested in why a `null` value wasn't returned in the mongo shell.

Answer (score 2):

In case you wonder, why MongoDB casts `undefined` to `null` instead of just ignoring such properties - `ignoreUndefined` flag could solve this behaviour.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/connecting/connection-settings/

Comment: Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [$exists to check for values that don't have the field](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

Comment: `$exists` will also return documents where the field is `null` - I'm not sure if the OP wants that or not.

Comment: `$exists : true` will return fields with `null`, `$exists : false` returns entries where the field isn't set.  Records with `null` values won't be returned.