# Using sort method in mongodb and getting error of Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, express

I am using Mongodb and trying to have my records sent back to me by sorting the `title` in ascending or descending order. I run the query like this on a route and for some reason I am getting this error:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined`

This is an example document from my db:

`{"title": "Bitcoin Business Seminar - Cryptocurrency Seminar"}`

Is this because title is a string right there? And if so how can I go around this?

Here is my query:

```
app.get('/API/offers/sort', (req, res, next) => {
    OfferController.find({}).sort({ title: 1 }, (err, results) => {
      if (err) {
        res.json(err);
        return;
      }

      res.json(results);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Where exactly does that exception happen? Whenever MongoDB says "undefined" it means "field not present". So this error is likely caused by an attempt to access (output?) a field that is not present in the document (perhaps because of a typo?). Also check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190651/mongodb-differentiates-between-undefined-vs-null

Comment: There are no typos im not sure where it is happening, I am just returning the full array and sorting it and returning the sorted array from there. I can't wait a long time to get this done.

Comment: You could try accessing your endpoint directly (/API/offers/sort) without your application around it and see what data you get back. I would think this should work and return some meaningful information. Then you will need to go back to your application and see what it attempts to do with this data and isolate the offending code.