# How to reach the data (in some field) in MongoDB that only set to null but not to undefined? Solved it was a bug in Compass

Tags: mongodb, null, set, undefined

How to reach the data (in some field) in MongoDB that only set to `null` but not to `undefined`?

I've tried `$exists: true` and `$and` but not succeeded.

What is the appropriate query for this?

[image]

Solved:
Is was bug in Compass this code works `{$and: [{ tripdurationr: {$exists: true}}, {tripdurationr: null}] }` but Compass add unwanted letter `r` to the key `tripduration` and because of this my query didn't work out. :)

Comment: Post your sample collection

Comment: ...and the query that's not working for you.

Comment: `{$and: [{ tripdurationr: {$exists: true}}, {tripdurationr: null}] }` doesn't  work

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct:

```
db.things.insert({a: null, b: 1});
db.things.insert({b: 2});
db.things.find({$and:[{a: null }, {a: {$exists: true}}]});
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0efa710d9b6861ee36052e"), "a" : null, "b" : 1 }
```

But beware of following:

```
db.things1.insert({a: null, b: 1});
db.things1.insert({b: 2});
db.things1.insert({ a: undefined, b: 3 });
db.things1.find({$and:[{a: null }, {a: {$exists: true}}]});
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0efe730d9b6861ee360531"), "a" : null, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5b0efe7b0d9b6861ee360533"), "a" : undefined, "b" : 3 }
```

Reference text to read for second part : "[MongoDB Differentiates Between undefined vs. null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190651/mongodb-differentiates-between-undefined-vs-null?rq=1)" and probably "https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-6102"